In Flask, my custom endpoint returns 404 in HTML despite having a JSON response
When trying to curl this endpoint with curl -X GET -i localhost:5000/person/66c09925-589a-43b6-9a5d-d1601cf53287
the implementation works fine:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Werkzeug/3.0.3 Python/3.12.3
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2024 13:19:49 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 294
Connection: close

{
  "address": "637 Carey Pass",
  "avatar": "http://dummyimage.com/174x100.png/ff4444/ffffff",
  "city": "Gainesville",
  "country": "United States",
  "first_name": "Lilla",
  "graduation_year": 1985,
  "id": "66c09925-589a-43b6-9a5d-d1601cf53287",
  "last_name": "Aupol",
  "zip": "32627"
}

but when I purposedly make a wrong request the server returns the error in HTML instead of JSON like I'm trying to implement on the /person endpoint
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
Server: Werkzeug/3.0.3 Python/3.12.3
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2024 13:02:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 207
Connection: close

<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>

I want to return  {"error_message":"person not found"}, 404
This is my endpoint in server.py with a hardcoded list
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
app = Flask(__name__)

data = [
    {
        "id": "66c09925-589a-43b6-9a5d-d1601cf53287",
        "first_name": "Lilla",
        "last_name": "Aupol",
        "graduation_year": 1985,
        "address": "637 Carey Pass",
        "city": "Gainesville",
        "zip": "32627",
        "country": "United States",
        "avatar": "http://dummyimage.com/174x100.png/ff4444/ffffff",
    }
]

@app.route("/person/<var_name>")
def find_by_uuid(var_name):
    for person in data:
        if person["id"] == str(var_name):
            return person
        else:
            return {"error_message":"person not found"}, 404

I tried to use the type:name syntax to only allow callers to pass in a valid UUID.
like this:
@app.route("/person/<type:var_name>")

the following is the full code from server.py:
gist

what do you get when you print(repr(var_name)) right before you return the error message?

also, I think you meant @app.route("/person/<uuid:var_name>")

tried that: does not work or returns anything

but when I detete the 2nd return it works and returns person...

I think I found the root of your problem: when you curl /person without a uuid, flask doesn't recognize it as /person/<var_name>, so it doesn't find a route

you are correct! Flask automatically returns HTML without a valid uuid. Thank you, so much

your for loop isn't actually looping through your data, since you are always returning in the first iteration. Putting the return {"error_message: ..."}, 404 after the loop should make it work.

that is what I did first: not having a "else:"

if I do that, the error message comes back in HTML and not in json as I implemented in the code

like a default error message

@AlanBitts returning the error inside the loop is definitely a logic error. Also notice that I can't reproduce any of your described issues with the code that you provided, so you clearly left something out which is important to the issues

I edited my original question and provided a Gist link to my API code

Flask automatically returns an HTML response as default 404 error message when I do not enter a valid request parameter.
